# Unable to train my keras model : (Data cardinality is ambiguous:)

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-classification, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am using the bert-for-tf2 library to do a Multi-Class Classification problem. I created the model but training throws the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-d9f382cba5d4> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit([INPUT_IDS,INPUT_MASKS,INPUT_SEGS], list(train.SECTION))

5 frames
/tensorflow-2.0.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in 
__init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, batch_size, epochs, steps, shuffle, **kwargs)
243             label, ", ".join([str(i.shape[0]) for i in nest.flatten(data)]))
244       msg += "Please provide data which shares the same first dimension."
--> 245       raise ValueError(msg)
246     num_samples = num_samples.pop()
247 

ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
x sizes: 3
y sizes: 6102
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

I am referring the medium article called [Simple BERT using TensorFlow 2.0](https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-bert-using-tensorflow-2-0-132cb19e9b22) 
The git repo for the library bert-for-tf2 can be found [here](https://github.com/kpe/bert-for-tf2/tree/master/bert).

Please find the entire code [here](https://gist.github.com/AmalVijayan/d7d50e5ea4af39760dc9b55daa840dec).

[Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1fIbPKxMayTgmRbFGQcC6tfY_6ZAXca-t) is a link to my colab notebook

Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, dunno why number of inputs and outputs should be same, this error appears to be raised from one of the data adaptors when x.shape[0] != y.shape[0], in this case

```
x = [INPUT_IDS,INPUT_MASKS,INPUT_SEGS]
y = list(train.SECTION)
```

so instead of

```
model.fit([INPUT_IDS,INPUT_MASKS,INPUT_SEGS], list(train.SECTION))
```

try giving inputs and outputs in a dictionary with the layer names (check model summary (suitable names can be explicitly given as well)), worked for me

```
model.fit(
     {
     "input_word_ids": INPUT_IDS,
     "input_mask": INPUT_MASKS,
     "segment_ids": INPUT_SEGS,
     },
    {"dense_1": list(train.SECTION)}
)
```

**please make sure** that the inputs and outputs are numpy arrays, for ex: using np.asarray(), it looks for .shape attribute